# Coldfusion cachedAfter and cachedWithin suggestion

Tags: caching, coldfusion

Alright, here is the thing..

My question is simple... If "cachedWithin" caches the query for specific time and "cachedAfter" caches the query after a specific time, then how do I cache a query "after 2 hours from now and cache it for 10 minutes?"

I want to cache a query after 2 hours from now and cache it for 10 minutes.. I've been following Fast Track to ColdFusion 9 but it doesn't have any example for my requirement.

Please help me with this. Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's an interesting tag.

So, what cachedafter is doing is saying that the query will be static after a specific time.

So, the following code would start to cache the query after 3PM server time today.

```
<cfset cachedate = CreateOdbcDateTime(dateformat(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd') & ' 15:00:00') />
<cfquery .... cachedafter="#cachedate#"....>
  QUERY
</cfquery>
```

More commonly, cachedwithin is telling Cold Fusion to only run this query every 6 hours.  I normally use this for data which might not be changing too often or data which takes a long time to load.

```
<cfquery ... cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0, 6, 0, 0)#" ...>
  QUERY
</cfquery>
```

[Better Explanation](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2008/3/18/cachedafter)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more examples demonstrating how cachedafter can be used.

Use it to refresh data once a day:

```
<cfquery .... cachedafter="#DateFormat( Now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD')#">
```

When the date rolls over tomorrow, the query will run and refresh.

Or, use it to run the same query only once per request:

```
<cfset Request.Cachetime = DateFormat( Now() ,"MM/DD/YYYY" ) & " " & TimeFormat( Now(), "HH:MM:SS.L" )>
<cffunction name="getstuff">
    <cfquery name="LOCAL.result" cachedafter="#Request.Cachetime#">
    ....
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn LOCAL.result />
</cffunction>
```

You could call getstuff() 100 times in the same request and it will only execute once against the database. Depending on your level of code reuse, this can come in pretty handy.

To answer the original question then, neither of these attributes by themselves will cache for 10 minutes after 2 hours. One option might be to create persistent variables in some scope to track now()+2 hours and now()+2:10, then set cachedwithin to 10 minutes only when now() is between those two times.